# Fetched Property works in iOS5 but not iOS6

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data, ios6, ios6.1

I am having a serious issue within my CoreData database. I have created a One To Many relationship between 2 tables and added a Fetched Property on the Table containing all unique values. All code works as expected within iOS 5 but in iOS 6 I receive the following errror:

> 2013-02-08 15:15:49.382 ArdsBoroughCouncil[16152:c07] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[<_NSObjectID_48_0 0xb25c3b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key tour_id.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x31c7012 0x24a3e7e 0x324ffb1 0x1c445ed 0x1bb08db 0x1bb088d 0x1bceb17 0x1bfe746 0x21b74bb 0x21b7176 0x21b6e44
>   0x21b66f4 0x21b2d63 0x21b2a82 0x21b2850 0x21b2625 0x21b1e07 0x21b18f4
>   0x21b0a6d 0x21ae9c9 0x2201276 0x227b155 0x2201071 0x2880014 0x286fd5f
>   0x286faa3 0x220103b 0x2200e9e 0x21ae9c9 0x2209dfa 0x22375cf 0x2237a03
>   0x59de1 0x11c2753 0x11c2a7b 0x11d0590 0x11d85bd 0x11d8eab 0x11d94a3
>   0x11d9098 0x1534da3 0x1526ad9 0x1526b54 0x24b7705 0x10e2920 0x10e28b8
>   0x11a3671 0x11a3bcf 0x11a2d38 0x111233f 0x1112552 0x10f03aa 0x10e1cf8
>   0x34b3df9 0x34b3ad0 0x313cbf5 0x313c962 0x316dbb6 0x316cf44 0x316ce1b
>   0x34b27e3 0x34b2668 0x10df65c 0x291d 0x2845) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminate called throwing an exception

The predicate defined for the Fetched Property is:

> ($FETCH_SOURCE.tour_id == tour_id) AND ($FETCH_SOURCE != SELF)

I have defined the array to return all receive all values within my Tour class.

Are you aware of any issues with Fetched Properties wihtin iOS 6 ? As I cannot understand this works with no issue in iOS 5 but fails in iOS6.

Please see all other related code below:

The code below is how I am retrieving all records:

```
- (void)loadRecordsFromCoreData {
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [self.managedObjectContext reset];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([Tour class]) inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:entityDescription];
        [request setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];
        [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tour_id" ascending:YES]]];
        self.tours = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    }];
```

The code below shoes the NSManagedObjects I have defined:

-- Tour

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class TourDetail;

@interface Tour : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tour_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * background_url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * summary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *tourdetails_tour;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tourDetails;
@end

@interface Tour (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addTourdetails_tourObject:(TourDetail *)value;
- (void)removeTourdetails_tourObject:(TourDetail *)value;
- (void)addTourdetails_tour:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeTourdetails_tour:(NSSet *)values;

@end
}
#import "Tour.h"
#import "TourDetail.h"


@implementation Tour

@dynamic tour_id;
@dynamic background_url;
@dynamic summary;
@dynamic title;
@dynamic tourdetails_tour;
@dynamic tourDetails;

@end
```

-- Tour Detail

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Tour;

@interface TourDetail : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tour_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * lattitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * audiofile;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * detail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Tour *tour_tourdetails;

@end

#import "TourDetail.h"
#import "Tour.h"


@implementation TourDetail

@dynamic id;
@dynamic tour_id;
@dynamic lattitude;
@dynamic longitude;
@dynamic audiofile;
@dynamic detail;
@dynamic title;
@dynamic tour_tourdetails;

@end
```

Any advise you can offer would be greatly appreciated :) As well as any examples you may have as to how best to define fetched properties ?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: just out of curiosity, how did you populate the db at the first place, and using what IOS 5 simulator?

Comment: Hi Space Dust I populated the db using mms dictionary objects that I then persisted using a model. This was done using the iOS5 simulator but even when I use the ios6 simulator the data is persisted but when I attempt to retrieve my fetched property the exception is thrown only with IOS6. Do you have any ideas on ow I could resolve this issue ?

Comment: Hi Michael, did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issues.

Comment: It's so weird I'm only having this with a **new** project running on iOS 6 simulator. It's not happening on 5.x, nor is it happening with an older project *even **in** the iOS 6 simulator*. Weird.

Comment: sounds to me like model a versioning problem. First step i try in these kind of situations is increasing the model version.

Comment: Hello Michael, did you find a solution to this? Got the same issue with Xcode 5.

Comment: Hi unfortunately not I ended up just retrieving each array of data individually using individual NSPredicates. From working with Core Data on a recent Mac app check your CoreData configuration again as I had made the mistake of trying to create linking tables for the relationships not realising that CoreData does all this for you. Hope you get it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The code your using here is not clean

```
- (void)loadRecordsFromCoreData {
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [self.managedObjectContext reset];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([Tour class]) inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:entityDescription];
        [request setResultType:NSManagedObjectResultType];
        [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tour_id" ascending:YES]]];
        self.tours = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    }];
```

In fact, it is a little confusing.

Your calling a method, that calls a managed object context, which further calls itself within a synchronous block, which resets itself for no reason, which sets a property 'self.tours' outside of the block.  All very odd.  Can you explain why you are doing this?

Try this instead.

```
+(void)loadRecordsWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSArray *records, NSError *error))completion {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context; //Your context
    NSError *error;
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"attribute" ascending:YES];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
    NSArray *records = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                              error:&error];
    completion(records, error);
}
```